# Clang dump ast but exclude imported files?

Tags: clang

Use clang to dump a objective-c file, but it will print all the imported files, so many useless info, is it possible just log out the class or method defined in this class?

The command is like this:

`clang -x objective-c -Xclang  -ast-dump -fsyntax-only -fobjc-arc  main.m`